# How to extract nested element with mouseenter in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, nested, mouseenter

I have some tree of comments. By default links at bottom of comment (like Edit or Reply) are hidden (via CSS). I need to show specific comment, which is under mouse.
OK, I use such code:

```
 $('[data-comment-id]').on('mouseenter', function(){
    console.log('mouseenter');
    $(this).find('.actionComment').css('visibility','visible');
});

$('[data-comment-id]').on('mouseleave', function(){
    console.log('mouseleave');
    $(this).find('.actionComment').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

It works with html like this (simplified version):

```
<div data-comment-id="1101">
  <span class="text">Text of comment</span>
 <span class="actionComment">[Links]</span>
     <div data-comment-id="1102">
       <span class="text">Text of comment 1</span>
       <span class="actionComment">[Links]</span>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Having mouse over nested div, I see that all elements (with class actionComment) is selected to be visible. But I would like to have in $(this) the nested element and show only his comments. Becouse of this dev are built by user's comments, the level of nesting might by any.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this?

```
$('[data-comment-id]').on('mouseenter', function(){
    console.log('mouseenter');
    $(this).find('.actionComment').css('visibility','visible');
});

$('[data-comment-id]>[data-comment-id]').on('mouseleave', function(){
    console.log('mouseleave');
    $(this).find('.actionComment').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

---

```
<div data-comment-id="1101">
    <span class="text">Text of comment</span>
    <span class="actionComment">[Links]</span>
<div data-comment-id="1102">
    <span class="text">Text of comment 1</span>
    <span class="actionComment">[Links]</span>
</div>
```

This is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/rngcz8ks/)

Comment: I missed closing div. Edited.